# How can I say the phrase “go places” in Chinese?

Tags: translation, phrase

I need a translation for the phrase as a whole not two words separately.

I need it in common Chinese if that’s a thing, but I mean the most general simple Chinese there is.

Comment: Can you first give the English meaning of the phrase, because "go places" can mean a lot of different things?

Comment: It's go place"s", not place.  If already happened: 经验老道 or 见过世面。If not yet happen 各处看看 or 走偏天下, based on the denotation of the phrase.  But River is right:  you do need to clarify the context.

Comment: Don't think "go places" has anything to do with travelling. :)

Comment: Obviously 'go places' = 去地方 is a  literal interpretation of an idiomatic expression

Comment: Hi guys, maybe I haven't made it clear enough. What I meant by to "go places" is to succeed. But the thing is I was hoping to find a phrase that says that in Chinese, not just the word 'succeed'. Hope it's clearer now. Thank you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a four-character chengyu (成語) I would offer "出人頭地" - to become head and shoulders above the rest.

She's a smart kid; one day she will go places.

她資質聰穎，有一天會出人頭地的。

Comment: Thanks a million! This is perfect! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

> Cambridge Dictionary: [Go places](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go-places): to be likely to be successful in the future:

It is "有好前途/ 有前途 " (have a great future) in Chinese

Example:

如果你想**有好前途**，你需要跟随我 - If you want to **go places** (have a great future), you need to follow me

這傢伙終有一天會**有好前途** - This guy will **go places** (have a great future) someday

You can also use **前途光明** (have a bright future)

Comment: Thank you this is great!